# Does setup.py's extras_require keyword support comma-separated extras?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Setuptools lets you list requirements for optional features

```
# mypackage
'extras_require' : { 'PDF' : ['reportlab'], 'DOCX' : ['docxlib'] }
```

and another package can specify `'requires' : [ 'mypackage[PDF]' ]`.

If another package wants to require more than one extra from the first package, can it ask for `'requires' : [ 'mypackage[PDF, DOCX]' ]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies

setuptools and pkg_resources use a common syntax for specifying a project's required dependencies. This syntax consists of a project's PyPI name, optionally followed by a comma-separated list of "extras" in square brackets, optionally followed by a comma-separated list of version specifiers

...so your answer is yes